# Creating parent model that all models will inherit from in Django

Tags: python, django, inheritance

I am attempting to create a model class that all models will inherit from when they are created (in Django). I want any model class, with any attributes to be able to inherit from this class and read from the appropriate database table.

I know I am going need to use `**kwargs` and `.setattr()` at some point but am unclear as to where I even start. I am also going to try to recreate `.all()`, `.filter()` and `.get()` with in that class that all other methods that inherit this class can access.

This is what I have so far:

```
import sqlite3

class Model:
def __init__(self):
    pass

@classmethod
def all(self, **kwargs):
    pass

@classmethod
def get(self):
    pass

@classmethod
def filter(self):
    pass


###don't touch the code for these
class Users(Model):
    pass

class Stocks(Model):
    pass
```

How can I go about the initialization of this class?

Comment: Why do you need to override them at all?

Comment: @ShangWang It is all theoretical. I am trying to gain a better understanding of inheritance and ORM.

Comment: Your approach is wrong. [The parent subclasses `models.Model`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance) (optionally with a meta-class with `abstract=True`, depending on how you want it to appear in your database), and your child classes inherit from that. You do not recreate ORM methods yourself.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance Please take a look at the doc, it will most likely provide what you need.

Comment: Since your parent class extends from models.Model it has all the ORM methods available, because it has a models.Manager. You don't need to write your owns ORM's methods.

Comment: There is a parent model,  django.db.models.Model.  I might suggest trying to work with an abstract Django model and looking at something very practical like extending the User model or implementing UUID per model that will get you in to inheritance.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're trying to insert an [abstract base class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes) for your models.

Basically, what you've got there is correct, except you're missing

```
from django.db.models import Model
class MyModelBase(Model):
     class Meta:
         abstract = True

     # ... The fields and methods I want all my models to inherit.
```

Then rather than making your models inherit from `django.db.models.Model`, they should inherit from `MyModelBase`.